# How to preserve long numbers in CasperJS when using command line options?

Tags: javascript, numbers, phantomjs, casperjs

When doing this:

```
casperjs somescript.js --number=736280854938322517687376855643288785
```

and in the code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var value = casper.cli.get("number");

console.log(value); // yields: 7.3628085493832246e+35
                    // want: 736280854938322517687376855643288785
```

I've looked and looked, pondered and hacked, but I'm not having much luck. The easy solution seems to be simply converting the number into a string. Or passing the number in as a string.  But the syntax for this eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [**Raw parameter values**](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html#raw-parameter-values):

> By default, the cli object will process every passed argument & cast them to the appropriate detected type[...]

You need to use `casper.cli.raw.get("number")` to get a non-parsed value. Since integer values that are bigger than 2<sup>53</sup> cannot be represented as an integer [without losing precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/1816580), you would need to work with them as a string or use some big integer library (such as [JSBN](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/)).

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that in the documentation. Cheers!